# Issue with clicking on a button

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I have a save button on my window whose html is

```
<div class="popup supportsLink editor">
    <h2></h2>
    <a class="close icon small" href="#"></a>
    <style></style>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/AirWatch/Blob/upload-blobs" data-name="blobform">
        <div class="editor"></div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="actions" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Save"></input>
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="closeClosestTray($(this));"></input>
```

I am not able to click on the save button. when i do an exists? in irb i get a true value. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Can you post your watir code?

Comment: i have used browser.button(:value=>"Save").click, browser.input(:value=>"Save).click and browser.form(:id=>"form0").click......nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to Watir and still am getting my bearings but maybe
browser.form(:value=>'Save').submit

If that doesn't work, is the button in a pop up? if so did you account for this?

so maybe something like this:

browser.window(:title => "annoying popup").use do
  browser.button(:id => "close").click
end

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get when you try clicking?
I made a page with your provided html and made script for clicking that and that normal code works for me, and it clicked that button and no error, I used:

```
browser.button(value: 'Save').click
```

Comment: I dont see any error when i run the command frm irb....its jus tat nothing happens on the browser.

Comment: Can you post any public link of your page ? Without having actual scenario, where many thing can relate with that, its getting unclear ! You can attach screenshot/attach video of manual clicking/posting full html of that page should also work !